# Firebase retrieving related data in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase. Not good at DB also.

I'm really hoping that people could give me advices about my DB design and retrieving data codes.

I designed the DB as below.

[image]

The comment have a createTs for ordering.But the content shouldn't ordered by create time. So I put a "index" key into contents info in the post.(I'm not sure if it is a good way)

About the data retrieving, I made a dataManager object to load data.

DataManger.swift

```
func loadPosts(completeBlock : ([Post]) -> Void ) {

    ref.child("posts").observeEventType(.Value , withBlock: { snapshot in

        var postList : [Post] = []
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {

        } else {
            for post in snapshot.children {

                let postSnap = post as! FIRDataSnapshot

                let post = Post()

                post.setValue(withSanpShot: postSnap)

                post.commentList = []

                for key in post.comments.keys {

                    self.loadPostComment(withKey: key, completeBlock: { (comment) in
                        post.commentList.append(comment)
                    })
                }

                post.contentList = []
                for key in post.contents.keys {

                    self.loadPostContent(withKey: key, completeBlock: { (content) in
                        post.contentList.append(content)
                    })
                }

                postList.append(post)
            }
        }

        completeBlock(postList)
    })
}

func loadPostComment(withKey key: String, completeBlock:(Comment) -> Void) {

    ref.child("post-comments").child(key).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { commentSnapShot in
        let comment = Comment()
        comment.setValue(withSanpShot: commentSnapShot)

        completeBlock(comment)
    })
}

func loadPostContent(withKey key: String, completeBlock:(PostContent) -> Void) {

    ref.child("post-contents").child(key).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { contentSnapShot in
        let content = PostContent()
        content.setValue(withSanpShot: contentSnapShot)

        completeBlock(content)
    })
}
```

And struct of the Post.swift.

```
class Post: NSObject {

    var postID : String
    var authorID: String
    var title: String
    var createTS : NSNumber
    var comments : [String : AnyObject]

    var contents : [String : AnyObject]

    var commentList : [Comment] {
        didSet {
            //TODO: add some closure to update view.Maybe also need sorting codes

            print("commentList : \(commentList)")
        }
    }
    var contentList : [PostContent] {
        didSet {
            //TODO: add some closure to update view.Maybe also need sorting codes

            print("contentList : \(contentList)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure the work I'v done is the right way to using it.Although I could got the data I want.

Please give me advices. That will be really helpful to me. Thanks.